# Delete all lines except first occurrence

Tags: text-processing

Given a space delimited text file, look for pattern in the first column. If found, keep the first occurence and delete the other lines:

Input (pattern = 1234):

```
1234    1111    2222
5678    3333    4444
1234    5678    9012
5678    1234    5678
1234    9786    5432
```

Expected Output:

```
1234    1111    2222
5678    3333    4444
5678    1234    5678
```

Comment: This should be very simple... Have you tried anything (search google) ?

Comment: For the life of me, I cannot match your desired output to your question!

Comment: Please make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to print all lines where the first field is not the specified value, and print the first line where it does match.

```
awk -vF="$1" '{ if ($1 != F) { print; } else {if (!seen) { print ; seen=1}}}'
```

Uses the fact that awk variables (`seen` in this case) have a value of 0 initially.

Comment: More compactly (making use of [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)), `awk -v F='1234' '$1 != F || !seen++' input`

Comment: I agree, that is pretty much what I would write for my own use (I wouldn't bother with setting the F variable, just get the quoting correct). I was going for clarity. I almost put in `$0` on the print statements to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Keep first matching line, and remove all subsequent matching lines with GNU sed:

```
sed -e '/^1234/{x;/./!{x;h;b;};d}' file
```

Explanation:

`/^1234/` when pattern buffer matches ^1234

`x` - swap the pattern and hold buffer (On the first match, the hold buffer will be empty, so the pattern buffer is now, crucially, empty)

`/./!` - Is the pattern buffer now empty?

`{x;h;b;}` - then swap (x) the pattern and hold buffer (This places the current line back in the pattern buffer), copy the pattern buffer into the old buffer (h), and branch to the end of execution for this line (b) - i.e. load the next line and start the sed code again. The final (d) delete doesn't get run.

`d` - after the first match, the hold buffer will contain a copy of the macthing line, so the {x;h;b;} block above will not execute - instead the current line gets deleted, the program ends, the next line is loaded into the pattern buffer and the program starts again.